# 2.9 Dynamic Paint Image Sequences Not Working (Nothing was painted on)

Tags: texturing, uv, dynamic-paint

I've been trying to recreate a project similar to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMDiSEl2WdE
My probem occured when I tried to generate the 180 frames of image sequences of the dynamic paint for further use as texture.

[image]

However, what I got in my directed folder were all black png images...
And I had a difficult time to figure out what had gone wrong..

[image]

Here's the detail of what I've done:

- Added a 2m x 2m Plane, uv-unwrapped and sub-divided twice + 50 cuts.
- Added a curve "ADF Path" based on "ARNODEFRANCE" text and set path animation to 160 frames.
- Added a Sphere with object constraint (follow path) and targeted to the curve "ADF Path", offset at 1.000.
- Applied Dynamic paint, type of Canvas to the Plane, type of brush to the Sphere.
- For the canvas, I selected Image Sequence, Resolution 2000, Frame start 1 end 180, sub-steps
  10 (tried also 20), set the initial color to black, UV map to "UV map".

[image]

- For the brush, I set the paint color to white and nothing changed from the default.

[image]

I then baked the image sequences, without premultiply Alpha since I do not want any alpha channel.

Yet, nothing was painted on the canvas...

Could anybody see right through the problem or mistakes I've done?

Thank you!